# Why proxy_pass in nginx is not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have following nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      root /telly_platform/frontend/public/pwa;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3030$request_uri;
    }
  }
```

When I perform a request to `http://localhost/api/path/resource` the request goes OK - where it needs to go - `http://localhost:3030/api/path/resource`.

But when I perform a request to `http://localhost:8080/api/path/resource` (with port `8080`) the request is not passed to the URL in `proxy_pass` directive, but is processed by first `location` block which returns `index.html` content.

What am I doing wrong and how to configure nginx to return API response even if it goes through 8080 port?

Thx!

Comment: Reverse the order of your `location` blocks.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, still the same result - `index.html` instead of json-response.

Comment: Okay. Take advantage of regex `location` blocks taking priority and change `location /api` to `location ~ ^/api`. The reason this is happening is because of `try_files` redirecting your `/api` request